# Avoiding Tables, Do and other loop construction

Tags: procedural-programming, built-in-symbols, iteration

In my work I have a lot of cases, where I should calculate non-listable functions for a quite large number of points. To be more concrete, consider first listable function `g[x,y,z]` and then I should first calculate

```
f[x, y] = NSolve[g[x, y, z] == 0 && a[x, y] < z < b[x, y], z]
```

where `a[x, y]` and `b[x, y]` are listable known functions.

I'm interested in a set of values `f[x, y]` for $x\in[-x_0,\,x_0]$ & $y\in[-y_0,\,y_0]$. To do it, I fix steps `dx` and `dy` and use `ParallelTable`. However, the evaluation consumes a lot of time. Is it possible to use available, built-in functions to improve performance?

Comment: You need to provide the definition of `f[x,y], a[x,y], b[x,y]` because there's nothing much else you can do and you've already got a ParallelTable.

Comment: @flinty ok, is it possible to make `NSolve` listable?